# Let $a_n = \frac{12n^2}{3n+4}-\frac{4n^2+3}{n+18}$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\text{Let}~ a_n=\frac{12n^2}{3n+4}-\frac{4n^2+3}{n+18}\\ \text{Find the 
 value of}~\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n~\text{correct up to 2 decimal places.}$$

Tried to apply L'Hôpital's rule, couldn't get anywhere. Tried doing the standard method for solving infinite limits, didn't workout either. The answer range is $66.60$ to $66.70$

Comment: combine the two fractions????

Comment: Look at the numerator. What is causing the problem? It is the $n^{2}$ part. Can it be remedied by a simple substraction? . What is $(12n^{3}-3n\cdot 4n^{2})$? . Can you solve it now?

Comment: I apologize for asking this question. I was overthinking it and missed the solution that was right in front of me. 
Thank you K.defaoite and @Mr.GandalfSauron  for the solution :)

Comment: The easiest way to with such questions is to combine the two fractions, then factor out the highest term from the numerator and do the same thing with denominator, then calculate the limit after reducing.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a simple trick to solve @belkacemabderrahmane :)

Comment: The value of the limit is $\frac{200}3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{12n^2}{3n+4}-\frac{4n^2+3}{n+18}=\frac{200n^2-9n-12}{(3n+4)(n+18)}\to \frac{200}{3}$, when $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: I shouldn't have made that answer. Now I understand. :)